# NETSH Command in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, wifi, netsh

I had read an article about making a wifi connection in Windows 7 using the Command Prompt. I have followed all the instructions from opening CMD to set up internet connection sharing. It is a process that I do:

1. Opening cmd and enter the command "netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=fahmi_wifi" key="abc12345"
2. Open the Windows Network and Sharing Center
3. Sharing the internet connection to the Virtual Wifi Miniport adapter
4. Running wifi with the command "netsh wlan start hostednetwork"

I also have opened cmd with admin privileges.
But, when I try it on another computer, the wifi says the following message: "No network access".

I use DHCP in my Wifi Adapter.

My question is:
How to solve this?
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the key without quotes: it worked for me.

Comment: can you please tell me how to create an "Open Network ( without password )" using netsh command..?